Groups having exactly two non real-valued irreducible characters
This is an enlarged version of my question on MSE. It was suggested I ask here instead.
Suppose the finite group $G$ has exactly two conjugacy classes that are not self-inverse (a conjugacy class is self-inverse if the elements in it are conjugate to their inverses). Let $x$ be an element of one of these classes, and suppose $x$ has order 4.
By Brauer's permutation lemma, $G$ has exactly two non-real valued ordinary irreducible characters, say $\chi$ and $\bar\chi.$ Write $\chi(x)=a+ib$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R.$ My questions:
A. Is it true that $a=0?$ Note, it's important that $x$ have order 4, or at least a power of 2. When $x$ merely has even order, then $a$ need not be zero (see note 1).
B. It's easy to show using characters that $|C_G(x)|$ is square (see note 2). Can this be proved without characters?
It would be great to have any progress towards either question, though I mainly ask (B) in case it would give any insight into the structure of $G,$ and so help towards (A).
Some notes and examples:

An example showing it is not enough to assume $x$ has even order is GAP SmallGroup(288,836), where the non-real elements have order 6 and $a=-1.$

As x has order 4, $a,b\in\mathbb Z.$ Also $0=\sum_{\psi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}\psi(x)^2$ and $|C_G(x)|=\sum_{\psi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}|\psi(x)|^2,$ and subtracting gives $|C_G(x)|=4b^2,$ a square as claimed. Actually $|C_G(x)|$ is a power of 4, since $x$ cannot commute with any element of $G$ of odd order.

Some examples of groups $G$ satisfying the conditions are the cyclic group of order 4, and more nontrivially GAP SmallGroup(192,1492) in which $|C_G(x)|=16.$

I can instead require that the conjugacy class of $x$ has odd length. This implies that $x$ is not self-inverse, so it strengthens the conditions on $G.$ Even in that case, I cannot prove $a=0,$ though I do randomly know that then if $a$ does $=0,$ then $G$ has a normal 2-complement.

Finally, $a=0$ would follow from a much more general conjecture: Let $G$ be any solvable group and suppose the matrix formed of the real-valued characters of $G$ on the self-inverse classes, is non-singular. Then every element of order a power of 2 is self-inverse. (There is a counterexample to this when $G$ is not solvable, but no solvable counterexamples in the GAP small group library.)



I tried looking at the case that the element $x$ of order $4$ is central in some Sylow $2$-subgroup, but I hit a difficulty wehn the $2$-part of the character degree $\chi(1)$ is exactly divisible by $2^{r}$, but $b$ is divisible by $2^{r+1}$. If that ever happens, then you do get $a \neq 0$ (maybe it never happens, but I could not immediately discount it).

I agree, in that case $a/2^r$ is odd. Actually there's then a promising start, by considering the sets $A_+={y\in x^G, xy\in x^G}$ and $A_-={y\in x^G, xy\in (x^{-1})^G}.$  Using the class multiplication formula, it follows that $|A_+|-|A_-|$ is not divisible by 4, but on the other hand if $P$ is the Sylow 2-subgroup with $x\in Z(P)$ then $P$ acts on $A_\pm,$ so you get an orbit of size 2. That leads to tempting structural information about $G,$ but frustratingly no answer, at least not in my hands :(

@TomWIlde this is totally unrelated to your question, but if you'd like the second letter in your last name in your username to be lowercase, I think a moderator could possibly help you with that...
